# Android SQLite issue during table creation "near ")": syntax error"

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing application where data from Web API is stored in database. 
My DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "LocalVenues.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";

    public static final String TABLE_VENUES = "venues";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING_COLOR = "rating_color";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "location_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHOTO_ID = "photo_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";


    //tips
    public static final String TABLE_TIPS = "tips";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_ID = "venue_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIP_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID = "user_id";

    //locations
    public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "lng";


    //authors
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "last_name";

    //photos
    public static final String TABLE_PHOTOS = "photos";
    public static final String COLUMN_PREFIX = "prefix";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUFFIX = "suffix";



    private static DBHelper dbHelperInstance;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbHelperInstance == null) {
            return dbHelperInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            return dbHelperInstance;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String STM_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE ";

        String STM_PRIMARY_KEY = "PRIMARY KEY ";
        String STM_FOREIGN_KEY = " FOREIGN KEY ";
        String STM_REFERENCES = " REFERENCES ";
        String STM_TEXT = " TEXT ";
        String STM_AUTOINCREMENT = " AUTOINCREMENT, ";

        String STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY = STM_TEXT + STM_PRIMARY_KEY;
        String STM_NOT_NULL = " NOT NULL, ";
        String STM_REAL = " REAL ";
        String STM_INTEGER = " INTEGER ";


        String CREATE_TABLE_VENUES = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_VENUES + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_VENUE_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING_COLOR + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHONE + STM_TEXT + ", " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_PRIMARY_KEY + STM_AUTOINCREMENT +
                COLUMN_ADDRESS + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAT + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LNG + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_TIPS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_TIPS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_VENUE_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_TIP_TEXT + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_VENUE_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_VENUES + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_USERS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_PHOTOS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PREFIX + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_SUFFIX + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_USERS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + " ( " + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + " ) " + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " ) "
                + ");";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VENUES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TIPS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);

    }

    //The simplest implementation of onUpgrade() method
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_VENUES);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_PHOTOS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_TIPS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_USERS);
        }
    }
}
```

I got error:  `E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ")": syntax error`
And as consequence I have another sub-question: Is there a way to make SQLite errors like this more informative?

Comment: is that the full log?

Comment: on which line you got the error?

Comment: @Lino, @Raghunandan yes, problem that this is actually all information that I got. In my service I check response, then use another wrapper class to store data. And after my log `I/Service: explore response is null: false` I got this line only.

Comment: @Autumn_Cat you have some columns missing form your table. I suggest you look at your create queries once again apart form the comma problem already suggested in my answer. I have tested the code that i posted it does not crash but its upto you to figure out how it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this

```
  String STM_NOT_NULL = " NOT NULL, ";
```

While running your code the logcat output was

```
  CREATE TABLE locations ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, address TEXT  NOT NULL, lat REAL  NOT NULL, lng REAL  NOT NULL, );
```

There is a extra comma at lng REAL  NOT NULL,)

You should get rid of that

And running your code further resulted in

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "photo_id" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tips ( _id TEXT PRIMARY KEY , venue_id TEXT  NOT NULL, user_id TEXT  NOT NULL, text TEXT  NOT NULL,  FOREIGN KEY (venue_id) REFERENCES venues(_id),  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(_id),  FOREIGN KEY (photo_id) REFERENCES photos(_id) );
```

There are some columns missing from your queries while creating table.

I am not sure how you want your table structure.

So i would suggest you look closely at your queries by looking at the logcat. You haven't posted enough details which you should see in logcat when your app crashes.

The below does not crash. Its very hard to post an answer without your full crash log.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "LocalVenues.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";

    public static final String TABLE_VENUES = "venues";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING_COLOR = "rating_color";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "location_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHOTO_ID = "photo_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";


    //tips
    public static final String TABLE_TIPS = "tips";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_ID = "venue_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIP_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID = "user_id";

    //locations
    public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "lng";


    //authors
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "last_name";

    //photos
    public static final String TABLE_PHOTOS = "photos";
    public static final String COLUMN_PREFIX = "prefix";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUFFIX = "suffix";



    private static DbHelper dbHelperInstance;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized DbHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbHelperInstance == null) {
            return dbHelperInstance = new DbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            return dbHelperInstance;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String STM_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE ";

        String STM_PRIMARY_KEY = "PRIMARY KEY ";
        String STM_FOREIGN_KEY = " FOREIGN KEY ";
        String STM_REFERENCES = " REFERENCES ";
        String STM_TEXT = " TEXT ";
        String STM_AUTOINCREMENT = " AUTOINCREMENT, ";

        String STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY = STM_TEXT + STM_PRIMARY_KEY;
        String STM_NOT_NULL = " NOT NULL, ";
        String STM_REAL = " REAL ";
        String STM_INTEGER = " INTEGER ";


        String CREATE_TABLE_VENUES = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_VENUES + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_VENUE_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING_COLOR + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHONE + STM_TEXT + ", " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";

       String CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_PRIMARY_KEY + STM_AUTOINCREMENT +
                COLUMN_ADDRESS + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAT + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LNG + STM_REAL + "NOT NULL"
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_PHOTOS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PREFIX + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_SUFFIX + STM_TEXT + "NOT NUll"
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_USERS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + " ( " + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + " ) " + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " ) "
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_TIPS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_TIPS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_VENUE_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_TIP_TEXT + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_VENUE_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_VENUES + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_USERS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";



        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VENUES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TIPS);


    }

    //The simplest implementation of onUpgrade() method
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_VENUES);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_PHOTOS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_TIPS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_USERS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your expanded answer. I understand your irritation but actually in my case the main problem that I got such poor log.  What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stands out is in your `CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS` String you are using `STM_NOT_NULL` that has a comma before closing the bracket. This results in the `, lng REAL NOT NULL,);` SQL syntax - and is't invalid. It could be one of the problems you're having. You should print all final strings out to `LogCat` (or take a look at them while debugging) to make sure the formatting is correct.

Comment: You're welcome - also please take a look at the timestamps of our answers. I did answer you first, and it was correct - and though another answer was edited later to provide more detail, complete disregard for my effort feels undue.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did something wrong. Yes, now I see that your answer was earlier. I'm quite new to SO etiquette. In such case should I reconsider and mark your answer as correct? And another question - what could be the reason of such poor log?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong - if you thought another answer was better, then it doesn't really matter which one came first. But an up-vote is a nice way to show you appreciate someone taking the time to dig into your issue if it was on point - so we're all good here.

Comment: You should log it manually - `Log.i("SQL table LOCATIONS", CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS)` should do it. You can do it for every SQL `String` you manually create. Just a note, you may way to look into something like ORMLight (http://ormlite.com/) and not have to write boilerplate SQL by hand.